# Send an email with Google Calendar Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Calendar Api to create an event in a gmail calendar. The event is well created and I have it in my gmail calendar but I would like that the attendees receive an email to accept or decline the meeting. Is anyone know how to do that ?

My back-end is coded in nodeJS.

Here is the characteristics of my event :

```
var event = {
'summary': 'Tes Calendar',
'location': 'Auditorium',
"sendNotifications": true,
'description': 'test calendar invitation',
'start': {
    'dateTime': '2017-08-31T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
},
'end': {
    'dateTime': '2017-08-31T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
},
'attendees': [
    {'email': '********@symphony.com'},
    {'email': '********@gmail.com'},
],
```

};

Thank you and have a great day ! 
Margot

Comment: I think you are already doing it because you set the sendNotifications to true.

Do you get any kind of error?

Comment: try to use the **Try this API** part of the [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) to create  an event

Comment: Thanks for your replies. In fact, I needed to wait to receive the reminder of the event by email ! So it works, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

When you call the insert method you must put the sendNotifications parameter like this :

```
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
  'calendarId': 'primary',
  'resource': event,
  'sendNotifications' : true
});
```